# Watch all properties of a reactive data in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I had an API call to the backend and based on the returned data, I set the reactive data dynamically:

```
let data = {
  quantity: [],
  tickets: []
}

api.default.fetch()
  .then(function (tickets) {
    data.tickets = tickets
    tickets.forEach(ticket => {
      data.quantity[ticket.id] = 0
    })
  })
```

Based on this flow, how can I set watcher for all reactive elements in quantity array dynamically as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a computed property, where you can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the quantity array, and then set a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on this computed property. Code will look something like following:

```
computed: {
  quantityString: function () {
      return JSON.stringify(this.quantity)
    }
}
watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
  quantityString: function (newQuantity) {
    var newQuantity = JSON.parse(newQuantity)
    //Your relevant code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Using the `[]` operator to change a value in an array won't let vue detect the change, use `splice` instead.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)